# Unable to get previous year value on summarization/rollup along with previous month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have dimension tables fct_department, Date and fact table fct_billing. I want to get the sum of fct_billing_amount for each month of the year for the list of department and fct_billing_amount for the previous month. For example if I have fct_billing_amount as $12,000 for the Month of Nov 22, I also want to see the value for fct_billing_amount, which is $10,000 for the previous month. But when the fct_billing_amount data for the listed department is rolled-up or summarized to year, I should get the value for the year 2022 which is $1,20,000 along with the total of fct_billing_amount for the year 2021 which is $1,10,000 which is for the previous year.I am trying to achieve the output in Power BI. The required out should be as mentioned in the image [Required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRIby.png)

Comment: Please share the code you have tried and the incorrect result it produced.

Comment: something like this `LY Sales = CALCULATE(SUM(fct_billing[amount]), SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(Date[day]))` , it does require the Date table to be properly defined (see more here: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/time-intelligence-in-power-bi-desktop/)

Comment: The code that I have written is as follows
Previous Month Billing Amount = 
    var a= CALCULATE(
        SUM(Fct_Billing[Fct_Billing_Amount])
        ,PREVIOUSMONTH(
            'Date'[Date].[Date]
        )
    )
    var b= CALCULATE(
        SUM(Fct_Billing[Fct_Billing_Amount])
        ,PREVIOUSYEAR(
            'Date'[Date].[Date]
        )
    )
    var selected_yr=SELECTEDVALUE('Date'[Year])
    var selected_mth=SELECTEDVALUE('Date'[Month])
return IF(ALL('Date'[Date].[Year])=selected_yr,a,b)

but its not working